# Connected to wireless, but no internet access

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 a week ago wireless internet had been working fine. It stopped working yesterday, however, and I'm at a loss for what to do even after scouring replies to similar posted problems.

I have tried using Google's public DNS and turning off proxy settings on Firefox. I have used nm-tool and lshw to make sure my wireless device and driver are connected. If anyone can help me resolve this issue I would be extremely grateful!

Outputs:

```
$ ping -c3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

---

```
$ ping -c4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.104 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
...
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3014ms
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

---

```
$ nm-tool | grep DNS
DNS: 192.168.1.1
```

---

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

---

```
$ ping -c4 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data
From 192.168.1.104 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unavailable
From 192.168.1.104 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unavailable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2998ms
pipe 4
```

---

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 88:ae:1d:58:9d:0b
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:16266 (16.2 KB)  TX bytes:16266 (16.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:15:35:ce:2c
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:15ff:fe35:ce2c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:109306 (109.3 KB)  TX bytes:27642 (27.6 KB)

wmax0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:64:da:04:52:b5
          UP NOARP  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:20
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 88:ae:1d:58:9d:0b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw
latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 57
       serial: 00:23:15:35:ce:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-34-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:43 memory:d4600000-d4601fff
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wmx0
       serial: 64:d4:da:04:52:b5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   15.388067] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   15.388072] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[   15.388180] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   15.388183] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc9000067c000
[   15.388186] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x57
[   15.388263] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.391065] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 41.28.5.1 build 33926
[   15.391352] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   15.391356] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   15.391358] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   15.391360] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE enabled
[   15.391362] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[   15.391365] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 AGN, REV=0x84
[   15.391427] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   15.399876] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x552, CALIB=0x6
[   15.399880] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Device SKU: 0x1F0
[   15.399883] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x3, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[   15.399910] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   15.510715] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   18.862936] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   18.863126] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   19.106527] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   19.106721] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 3754.102289] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 3754.102506] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.103049] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.114930] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.114945] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.114957] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.115002] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.115039] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.115049] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.116099] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.128114] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3754.138152] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3756.419608] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 3756.421101] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 3756.421286] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 3762.839399] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 3762.840221] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 3776.333700] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 3776.335758] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 3776.335951] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 4214.253483] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 4214.253686] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 4305.514303] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 4305.514509] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

---

Comment: First things first, is your wireless button(switch) on? Can you see any listed networks. Go to a terminal (ctr+alt+t) and type `ping -c 3 www.google.com` What do you get?

Comment: What is the output of `ping -c4 8.8.8.8` ? If it did ping, what's the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `nm-tool | grep DNS`? Also, you mentioned you turned off proxy. Is your network in fact using a proxy?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Alaa. 

ping -c4 8.8.8.8 gives: 
`PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.104 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
...
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3014ms pipe 3`

cat /etc/resolv.conf gives:
`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1`

and nm-tool | grep DNS gives:
`DNS: 192.168.1.1`

Comment: Hmm. What's the output of `route -n` and `ping -c4 192.168.1.1`. Also, you haven't answered the proxy question. Is your network behind a proxy? Also, instead of posting the output in the comment, you can post the output in your question by editing your question, and then post a comment "Added info to my question" =). Look for "edit" underneath your question. If you can't find it, click [here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/313687/edit).

Comment: Nope, not behind a proxy. I meant that in Firefox advanced preferences I selected no proxy.

Comment: Okay, cool. So what's the output of the two commands in my comment above? These should give us the answer.

Comment: (Initially posted as an answer by [kregerjd](http://askubuntu.com/users/159773/kregerjd)) First things first, is your wireless button(switch) on? Can you see any listed networks. Go to a terminal (ctr+alt+t) and type `ping -c 3 www.google.com` What do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your patience @Alaa! I updated my question with the output.

Comment: For the sake of learning, would you mind telling me what you're looking for in this output?

Comment: I'm checking for connectivity and correct settings. I'll give a full explanation when we solve the problem =). However, so far, everything seems correct, but you can't even ping your gateway. What's the output of `ifconfig`, `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, and `sudo lshw -C network`? Did you change any settings using nm-tool? Did you set static IP settings?

Comment: Your wireless router might have picked up wrong DNS settings. Does it work with other machines/devices (eg. phone)? As a side note I noticed that the `192.168.1.0` network's metric is 2. It used to be 1 (although it does not make any difference).

Comment: @Alaa: I did not change settings using `nm-tool` and I did not set static IP settings. (Also, thanks for cleaning up my post :D)

Comment: @lgarzo: My wireless is working with my phone and other laptops.

Comment: The WiMax interface is up and has NOARP. I'm wondering if this NOARP is affecting the packets coming out of the WiFi interface. I've looked around and this might be some kind of firmware problem? Calling @chili555 ! @boogaloo, I'm sure chili would probably want to see the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: Hi @Alaa, I've updated the post with `dmesg` output

Comment: Um, okay I'm at a loss, so we'll try a couple of things. Do `rfkill unblock all` (you shouldn't see any output), and try the wireless. If it didn't work, then we'll also try to disable N-wireless (known for some issues): do `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`, cross your fingers, and check.

Comment: Hmm, no go :\ My computer disconnected and then connected to the network, but internet pages still failed to load. I really appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: Try to boot with an older kernel. What happened before the network stopped working, any updates installed.

Comment: boogaloo says that the network interface is not statically configured. So it was configured via DHCP. So DHCP packets are exchanged with the modemrouter. But ICMP and other kinds of packets are not. Hmm.

Comment: I assume that you turning the wifi switch on and off to check it? Just asking because I see that in dmesg. Is it possible your network card somehow went into some mode other than Managed? You can do a reset to managed with: `ifconfig wlan0 down`
`iwconfig wlan0 mode managed`
`ifconfig wlan0 up`
`service network-manager restart`

Comment: Just a thought, is it possible that you have a firewall rule that is forcing traffic through a vpn interface? I say that because the script I use to start my vpn includes changes to the firewall to only allow traffic through tun0. Sometimes I forget to run my script to revert back to firewall rules that allow traffic through my wlan0 interface. When I do that, I see the same symptom that you're reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the inbuilt network connections manager saying everything was fine, and ifconfig reporting the correct network addresses and that the connection was up and running, I could ping my laptop from the pc but had no internet access.

In my case it was down to also having a GUI network manager, Wicd, which must have been intercepting the connection, because by enabling the wireless lan via the GUI interface, the internet access came back up.

Hope this helps.